# retrieving single object from json in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have searched far and wide, I have a long history with Angular and am sorta new to the world of React. I am looking to retrieve a single item at a time from my json file. The data is synced and it loops into render flawlessly. This would be .map(), however I do not wish to display all items in the json at once. I would like to show 1 item, then click through with navigation I have set up to show each one individually. In Angular this is done by doing something like this data[0].item index item displays.

Any ideas? Thank You

Comment: Read this: [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide more explanation and a sample JSON and/or code so we can help

Comment: Here are 2 images 1 is of the call to axios 2 is of the .map which renders to the screen. I do not want to loop through and display every image. Just one image at a time then use navigation too click through, sort of like a photo carousel. http://imgur.com/a/Xf8El     http://imgur.com/a/Xf8El

Comment: I deleted the map all together and did props.articles[index].item, works. Thanks guys